# Angular 2 *ngFor doesn't display data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm working on an application using Ionic 2 together with Angular 2. Now I'm trying to the data from an API and display this on a page.

I can log the data and I think it's correct, but for some reason nothing is being displayed on the page itself:

[image]

The API where I'm receiving the data from is located here: http://peerligthart.com/grotekerk/v1/api.php/zerken?transform=1

***ngFor on my view**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <h1 *ngFor="let z of zerken">
    {{ z.naam }}
  </h1>
</ion-content>
```

**Controller**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PopoverPage } from '../popover/popover';

import { ZerkenProvider } from '../../providers/zerken';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-lijst',
  templateUrl: 'lijst.html',
  providers: [ZerkenProvider]
})

export class LijstPage {

  zerken: Array<any>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public popoverCtrl: PopoverController, public zerkenProvider: ZerkenProvider) {
    this.zerkenProvider.getZerken().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data.zerken);
        this.zerken = data.zerken.results;
      }
    )
  }

  openPopover(event) {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopoverPage);
    popover.present({
      ev: event
    });
  }

}
```

**And last, the provider**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ZerkenProvider {

  static get parameters() {
    return [[Http]];
  }

  constructor(public http: Http) {

  }

  getZerken() {
    var url = "http://peerligthart.com/grotekerk/v1/api.php/zerken?transform=1";
    var response = this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
    
    return response;
  }

}
```

So, what the page is displaying itself:

[image]

As you can see.. nothing. I hope someone has a solution, kind regards!

**-------------EDIT-------------**

I changed `this.zerken = data.zerken.results` to `this.zerken`. After doing this it's giving me an error:

[image]

Comment: What if you inspect the DOM? Is the HTML list actually generated? It could simply be hidden in CSS or something.

Comment: Try with this `<h1 *ngFor="let z of zerken | async">`

Comment: @GangadharJannu async would be when `zerken` itself is a promise or observable

Comment: you are not getting any errors in logs..?

Comment: use this.zerken= data.zerken

Comment: initialize zerken =[];
you please do 
 console.log(this.zerken); to check , wheher your object array is being inserted in zerken[]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `zerken` in your response doesn't seem to have an `results` object, so

```
this.zerken = data.zerken.results;
```

should be:

```
this.zerken = data.zerken;
```

Remember to initialize the array in your component:

```
zerken: Array<any> = [];
```

so that you won't get an error that zerken is undefined, since view is usually rendered before data has been received. Having it initialized will prevent that.

Comment: upvote for right answer, but the `z?` is not necessary here. `zerken` is either undefined or populated with an array

Comment: but shouldnt the `ngFor` give error if `zerken` is initially null?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/5f71ee5af1ea42eee4b52659f28f8c7a receiving this error when i change the data set.. (it is populated with an array yes, since zerken is an array)

Comment: @Peurr, seems you are having the async pipe in your template, remove it, and it should work :)

Comment: @Peurr and initialize the array as `zerken: Array<any> = [];`

Comment: @PierreDuc having brain dysfunction, meant that array should be initialized :D Thanks for pointing that out my "error" :)

Comment: @AJT_82 No problem :D Also array initialisation is not really necessary. No template error will occur. But it is advicable nevertheless

Answer (score 2):

You need an `*ngIf` encapsulating the `*ngFor` since `zerken` is obtained at a later point of time.

Try:

```
<ion-content padding>
 <div *ngIf="zerken">
  <h1 *ngFor="let z of zerken">
    {{ z.naam }}
  </h1>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

Also you need to set `zerken = data.zerken;` as mentioned in the other answer by @AJT_82.

Comment: just curious about , what was the significance of *ngIf here?

Comment: its similar to your safe navigation..zerken is null before subscribed value is received..